# Word or phrase for a sudden change of day to night

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word of phrase that would describe the abrupt change of day to night, similar to what you can witness closer to the Earth's equator. The phrase will be used for a name of a tune.
Something that comes to my mind is in the lines of:

> night's break in
>
> barging of night

but I am unable to find this exact wording used anywhere

Comment: What's wrong with ***nightfall**?* As a rule, things tend to ***fall*** pretty quickly.

Comment: Hi Max, welcome to English Language & Usage. You might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. *You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used*."  You can add this using the [edit] link. For further guidance, see [ask], and make sure you also take the **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: To add to @FumbleFingers suggestion, which I think is the correct one, you may care to read about [Asimov's famous ***Nightfall***](https://www.publishersweekly.com/978-0-385-41626-9), which deals with civilization-spanning consequences of the unexpected arrival of night.

Comment: Would something like "eclipse" work as a song title for you? Obviously, it's not literal but it is somewhat poetic and sudden.

Answer (score 0):

- Plunged into darkness.
- Plunged into night.
- The city was plunged into darkness.
- The planet was plunged into night.